# error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, lua

I'm trying to set up the environment of deepmind/dqn, https://github.com/deepmind/dqn, I run ./install_dependencies.sh to install

```
LuaJIT and Torch 7.0
nngraph
Xitari
AleWrap
```

first.But I got:

```
/home/dqn/torch/bin/luajit: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

 - => Torch7 has been installed successfully

   Installing nngraph ... /home/dqn/torch/bin/luajit: error while
   loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object
   file: No such file or directory Error. Exiting.
```

**The install_dependencies.sh is:**

```
# Install dependencies for Torch:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -qqy build-essential
sudo apt-get install -qqy gcc g++
sudo apt-get install -qqy cmake
sudo apt-get install -qqy curl
sudo apt-get install -qqy libreadline-dev
sudo apt-get install -qqy git-core
sudo apt-get install -qqy libjpeg-dev
sudo apt-get install -qqy libpng-dev
sudo apt-get install -qqy ncurses-dev
sudo apt-get install -qqy imagemagick
sudo apt-get install -qqy unzip
sudo apt-get update


echo "==> Torch7's dependencies have been installed"





# Build and install Torch7
cd /tmp
rm -rf luajit-rocks
git clone https://github.com/torch/luajit-rocks.git
cd luajit-rocks
mkdir -p build
cd build
git checkout master; git pull
rm -f CMakeCache.txt
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
RET=$?; if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then echo "Error. Exiting."; exit $RET; fi
make
RET=$?; if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then echo "Error. Exiting."; exit $RET; fi
make install
RET=$?; if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then echo "Error. Exiting."; exit $RET; fi


path_to_nvcc=$(which nvcc)
if [ -x "$path_to_nvcc" ]
then
cutorch=ok
cunn=ok
fi

# Install base packages:
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install cwrap
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install paths
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install torch
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install nn

[ -n "$cutorch" ] && \
($PREFIX/bin/luarocks install cutorch)
[ -n "$cunn" ] && \
($PREFIX/bin/luarocks install cunn)

$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install luafilesystem
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install penlight
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install sys
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install xlua
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install image
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install env

echo ""
echo "=> Torch7 has been installed successfully"
echo ""


echo "Installing nngraph ... "
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks install nngraph
RET=$?; if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then echo "Error. Exiting."; exit $RET; fi
echo "nngraph installation completed"

echo "Installing Xitari ... "
cd /tmp
rm -rf xitari
git clone https://github.com/deepmind/xitari.git
cd xitari
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks make
RET=$?; if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then echo "Error. Exiting."; exit $RET; fi
echo "Xitari installation completed"

echo "Installing Alewrap ... "
cd /tmp
rm -rf alewrap
git clone https://github.com/deepmind/alewrap.git
cd alewrap
$PREFIX/bin/luarocks make
RET=$?; if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then echo "Error. Exiting."; exit $RET; fi
echo "Alewrap installation completed"

echo
echo "You can run experiments by executing: "
echo
echo " ./run_cpu game_name"
echo
echo " or "
echo
echo " ./run_gpu game_name"
echo
echo "For this you need to provide the rom files of the respective games (game_name.bin) in the roms/ directory"
echo
```

**when I test the code ./run_gpu {game_name}, I got:**

```
../torch/bin/luajit: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**when I run ldconfig -p | grep readline
My version is below 6**

```
libreadline.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
libreadline.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so
libguilereadline-v-18.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libguilereadline-v-18.so.18
libguilereadline-v-18.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libguilereadline-v-18.so
```

**but I cannot install libreadline7 by : sudo apt-get install libreadline7-dev**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libreadline7-dev
```

**How could I tackle the installation of libreadline7??**

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly due to anaconda, try disable that from you PATH

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this dependency you need to manually install the mentioned package. go to ubuntu store and search for the package.

> https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libreadline7&searchon=names

this will list the package information. Click on the hyperlink provided in the package description. In this case :

> https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libreadline7

click on any link for your region. this will start download of the debian file for the package.

once you have got the debian file you simply have to install it using dpkg command

eg :

> sudo dpkg -i Desktop/libreadline7_7.0-3_amd64.deb